# LocalProcessingException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, parameters, report, reportviewer

Trying to Test my Report and then Error message says:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
>   Additional information: An error occurred during local report processing."

Any idea why would i face such an Error?!

Comment: This is the most generic error using `LocalReport`: you have to check the `InnerException.Message` to have more info about the problem.

Comment: Mr. @tezzo i'm not familiar on InnerException things , so i'v tried this way: 


**Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("file1", "file2")
        Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
        End Try**

And it return Nothing ,is there another way to find out the **InnerException.Message** or something ?

Comment: This is correct as syntax but you have to catch the `LocalProcessingException` and then check its `InnerException.Message`. Debug your application and verify which line throws this `Exception` (maybe is a call to `.Render` or a `.RefreshReport`).

Comment: Sir @tezzo, finally i got the "ex.InnerException" which is : 

"{"The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."}"  .

Would you please help me fixing it!

Comment: Is it a "reportviewer" Versions Error ? i'm using "VS2010", if this may help find out the Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `VS2010` and the `InnerException` says that:

```
The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/…; which cannot be upgraded.
```

So you have to use the correct `ReportViewer` library which is the `10.0`.

Comment: where you find it disabled? in the Add Reference > .NET window?

Comment: In the Toolbox > Reporting > ReportViewer 10.0

Comment: try delete and readd a reference to `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` 10.0.